# Pull item after inject.service()

Tags: ember.js

I have a service

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
products: [],
add(product) {
   this.get('products').pushObject(product);
},
```

in template I call it

```
 <a href="{{href-to 'products' (query-params search=item.label)}} {{action 'add' item }}">
```

and my component controller has this action

```
  searchProduct: Ember.inject.service(),
  ...
  ...

  add(item) {
    this.get('searchProduct').add(item);
  }
```

So when I click and move to route - products I am not able to pull what I injected. My products controller has the following.

```
passedSearchQuery: computed('searchProduct.products.[]', function() {
   return this.get('searchProduct.products').slice(-1).pop();
}),
```

What I am missing? Thank you!

Comment: your action is inside the href attribute

Comment: and also we should not prevent default behavior otherwise only `add` method will be triggered but not anchor tag default behavior. so to make it call both actions we need to set `preventDefault=false` to action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `href-to` will just simply just return created url. also it will not support event handling.
- Include `preventDefault=false` to action helper.

  `<a href="{{href-to 'products' (query-params search=item.label)}}" {{action 'add' item preventDefault=false}}>`

Comment: I would be happy to remove my answer if some one said the reason. by the way @Askar does this work out for you?

Comment: let me try that .  I will let you know.

Comment: I added computed onSearch: Ember.computed('searchProduct.products.[]', function() {
   return this.get('searchProduct').pop(this);
  }),
 
and also pop function in service. 
 pop(product) {
          this.get('products').popObject(product);
  },

i run {{onSearch}} on template but it does not seem work.  I am not sure how to test it .

Comment: `this.get('searchProduct').pop(this)` - instead of `this`, i think you need to pass exact `item` to pop out. You can edit your question with popObject code related stuff.. You can say `console.log('Object ',this.get('searchProduct.products'));` this will print entire object what is inside to console.

Comment: it does not like that - 'VM1053:1 Uncaught TypeError: this.get is not a function(…)'

Comment: Your service creates a normal array, however you are observing changes in your computed like so 'products.[]' - normal arrays don't have change notification like Ember.A().

Comment: `pop` method in service should return popped out product item..  `return this.get('products').popObject(product);` still you are sending `this` argument instead of an product object  to  `pop` in service from `onSearch` computed property. what do you expect onSearch should return to your template?

Comment: @xoma you can do that. I am watching products hash and poping last element. I did manual seeds and I am able to pull them. It seems something happening when I am trying to run add from component.

Comment: Now your code looks correct to me. so keep it remember `passedSearchQuery` this will be recalculated only when you add/remove items in `searchProducts.product` array not while modifying product item properties. and also when you actually use/call `passedSearchQuery` only then this will be called..with that in mind consider creating [ember-twiddle.com](http://ember-twiddle.com) to demonstrate. that would be easy to debug.

Comment: inside the component I added to template   <button class="btn" {{action 'add' item}}>
    {{item.label}}
   </button>

then in component.js when I do console.log('Item object: ', this.get('item'));

I get - "Item object:  undefined"

Comment: Is component.js add function is accepting item as first argument

Comment: @kumkanillam I refactored. It seems this.get('item') did not get argument.